# Why doesn't mysql use the index key?

Tags: mysql, key, describe

I have 1 table `locations` and 4 identical tables: `countries`, `regions`, `provinces`, `cities`

All tables are InnoDB

All tables have a column `id` which is Primary, Non-Null, Unsigned Int, Auto-Increment

All tables have a column `name` which is Non-Null, VarChar, default ''

`locations` holds foreign keys to all other 4 tables. All Non-Null.

The `locations` table also holds some other columns and indexes/keys, but none not related to the other 4 tables

Now I have this query:

```
DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM locations
LEFT JOIN cities ON locations.city_id = cities.id
LEFT JOIN provinces ON locations.province_id = provinces.id
LEFT JOIN regions ON locations.region_id = regions.id 
LEFT JOIN countries ON locations.country_id = countries.id
WHERE locations.id > 1
```

The result is to my satisfaction: all tables use their key.

```
1, SIMPLE, locations, range , PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4,                           , 393, Using where
1, SIMPLE, cities   , eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, mydb.locations.city_id    ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, provinces, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, mydb.locations.province_id,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, regions  , eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, mydb.locations.region_id  ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, countries, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, mydb.locations.country_id ,   1,
```

**Question** :

Changing only `LEFT JOIN countries` into `INNER JOIN countries` is ok. All tables still use keys.

```
1, SIMPLE, locations, range , PRIMARY,locations_country_id_fk, PRIMARY, 4,                              , 341, Using where
1, SIMPLE, cities   , eq_ref, PRIMARY                        , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.city_id    ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, provinces, eq_ref, PRIMARY                        , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.province_id,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, regions  , eq_ref, PRIMARY                        , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.region_id  ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, countries, eq_ref, PRIMARY                        , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.country_id ,   1,
```

Changing only `LEFT JOIN provinces` into `INNER JOIN provinces` is ok. All tables still use keys.

```
1, SIMPLE, locations, range , PRIMARY,locations_province_id_fk, PRIMARY, 4,                              , 341, Using where
1, SIMPLE, provinces, eq_ref, PRIMARY                         , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.province_id,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, regions  , eq_ref, PRIMARY                         , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.region_id  ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, countries, eq_ref, PRIMARY                         , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.country_id ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, cities   , eq_ref, PRIMARY                         , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.city_id    ,   1,
```

Changing only `LEFT JOIN cities` into `INNER JOIN cities` is ok. All tables still use keys.

```
1, SIMPLE, locations, range , PRIMARY,locations_city_id_fk, PRIMARY, 4,                              , 341, Using where
1, SIMPLE, provinces, eq_ref, PRIMARY                     , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.province_id,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, regions  , eq_ref, PRIMARY                     , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.region_id  ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, countries, eq_ref, PRIMARY                     , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.country_id ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, cities   , eq_ref, PRIMARY                     , PRIMARY, 4, ftc_dev.locations.city_id    ,   1,
```

But changing only `LEFT JOIN regions` into `INNER JOIN regions` is **NOT** ok. The `regions` table doesn't use its key. I get this:

```
1, SIMPLE, regions  , ALL   , PRIMARY                       , null                  , null, null                      , 269, 
1, SIMPLE, locations, ref   , PRIMARY,locations_region_id_fk, locations_region_id_fk,    5, mydb.regions.id           ,   1, Using where
1, SIMPLE, cities   , eq_ref, PRIMARY                       , PRIMARY               ,    4, mydb.locations.city_id    ,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, provinces, eq_ref, PRIMARY                       , PRIMARY               ,    4, mydb.locations.province_id,   1, 
1, SIMPLE, countries, eq_ref, PRIMARY                       , PRIMARY               ,    4, mydb.locations.country_id ,   1,
```

This is weird! Because `countries`, `regions`, `provinces`, `cities` are identical as far as I can see! But this behaviour proves the 4 tables are **not** identical (towards the `locations` table). What could I have missed looking at to make them more identical?

I have already looked at `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name'` and `DESCRIBE table_name`. Almost everything is identical. And where there are changes (eg `rows`, `avg_row_length`, `data_length`, `auto_increment`, `create_time`), the `regions` table values are always somewhere in between of the other values.

**Edit: Why I'm asking:**

Query with LEFT JOIN on regions takes approx 350ms (duration: 10ms, fetch: 340ms).

Query with INNER JOIN on regions takes about 550ms. (duration: 330ms, fetch: 220ms).

(Not exactly knowing, but guessing this has to do with not being able to cache ?!)

**Edit2:**

Query with STRAIGHT_JOIN on regions performs as good as LEFT JOIN and provides the same output as INNER JOIN. This is good. But still it doesn't help me answer WHY the `regions` table behaves differently. Where should I look to spot the actual difference between `regions` and the other 3 seemingly identical tables.

Comment: Just added an edit, to point out that the INNER JOIN is SLOWER than the LEFT JOIN

Comment: As @Kickstart points out, besides INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN, I could also do STRAIGHT_JOIN. This seems to have the same output as INNER JOIN, but with the same performance as LEFT JOIN. This is good. But still I need to figure out, why the `regions` table. What makes this table so different?!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is down to the data.

The locations.id > 1 is probably not much use to narrow down the data at all, and I suspect locations has many records.

Regions probably has less records, so using this as the primary table to join others to is probably more efficient. Ie, you original query hangs all the joins off locations which limits it to 393 rows, while your 2nd query hangs the joins off regions which is only 269 rows.

You can use a STRAIGHT_JOIN if you wish to force the order of the joins.

Comment: `locations.id > 1` is done for arguments sake only; just to make even the `locations` table use a key. I don't expect the `locations` table to be identical. Only the 4 `cities`, `regions`, `provinces` and `countries` should be identical.

Comment: You could probably use regions.id > 1 for much the same effect to force an index to be used on regions. MySQL has merely chosen the table with the smallest number of records (taking the key fields specified) to join the other INNER JOINed tables against.

Comment: That is the funny part! The `provinces` table for example have even **less** records than the `regions` table. But for that table it doesn't matter. And the `cities` table has **more** records than the `regions` table. And for that table it also doesn't matter! So it doesn't seem related to the number of rows inside each of the 'identical' tables.

Comment: Provinces result does sound strange. Could you do each of the queries and post the explains in your original post?

Comment: It is the relative quantities in the columns I wanted to see.

Comment: I have 393 countries. 144 provinces. 269 regions. 9283 cities.

Comment: Afraid I am not sure, unless it is something odd with the distribution of the id records on provinces relative to regions, or (unlikely) you need to run analyze table on each of them.

Comment: This seems true btw, but doesn't really help me understand WHY this is: *You could probably use regions.id > 1 for much the same effect to force an index to be used on regions.*

Comment: It is just that it has chosen to use the regions table first, and then that is an index that can narrow down the results a tiny amount. But unrelated to why it has chosen to use the regions table first and why it doesn't use provinces first when that is changed to an INNER JOIN. Of your 144 provinces and 269 regions how many of each are used in the locations table?

Comment: Yeah. And the fact that it really impacts query time negatively. Query with `LEFT JOIN` would take approx 350ms (duration: 10ms, fetch: 340ms). But with `INNER JOIN` on `regions` takes about 550ms. (duration: 330ms, fetch: 220ms). Not exactly knowing, but guessing this has to do with not being able to cache ?!

Comment: What happens if you use a STRAIGHT_JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN? Using this you should be able to force an INNER JOIN, but with locations as the primary table. I would generally expect an INNER JOIN to be faster than an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: A STRAIGHT_JOIN performs just as good as a LEFT JOIN (which is good). Again duration goes to 10ms and the fetch goes to about 340ms, totaling on 350ms. And again, "using temporary, using filesort" no longer appears in the DESCRIBE. What could it be with the `regions` table I haven't spotted yet!? There must be something funky with this table.

Comment: Looks like it is one of those times where MySQL does decide to use the wrong order. I presume you have run analyze table on the tables recently. Without the actual tables and data to play with I am not sure I can suggest much more.

Comment: Analyze just returns OK. For both `regions` as `locations`

Comment: Analyze should return OK, but it should also sort out the statistics that MySQL uses to decide which indexes to use.